# Gracefully stopping tomcat in docker

Tags: tomcat, docker

I have the following requirement on my docker container running tomcat:

1. Start tomcat as background process(catalina.sh start)
2. Run app specific configuration
3. Stop tomcat(catalina.sh stop)
4. Start tomcat in foreground.(catalina.sh run)

However, I am not able to get this working as the app configuration is started before tomcat has initialized. Also, step no 4 fails as tomcat is still in the shutdown process.

How do I change this process to:

1. Start tomcat as background process
2. Wait for startup
3. Run app specific config
4. Shutdown tomcat
5. Wait for shutdown
6. Start tomcat as foreground process.

I have hacked the following so that my dev activities can proceed, but the following code will not shutdown tomcat properly if the container is stopped.

```
case $COMMAND in
    start )
        echo "Configuring OpenAM.."
        cp /artifacts/openam.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/openam.war
        cat /opt/openam-install.properties
        /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        sleep 20
        ls -lart
        cd /artifacts/configurator
        unzip configurator.zip 
        java -jar openam-configurator-tool-13.5.0.jar --acceptLicense --file /opt/openam-install.properties
        echo "Configuration Complete."
        tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
        ;;
```

As you might have guessed. I am terrible at writing shell scripts. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: From what I understand, In order to gracefully stop tomcat I will need to send a SIGTERM to the catalina process. If I start tomcat in the background and then there is no way docker can send a SIGTERM to that process. This means that after a delay of 10 seconds, docker will send a SIGKILL signal to all the process, which will kill my catalina process without giving it a chance to shutdown properly. Therefore, I want to start tomcat using exec catalina.sh run to keep it running in the foreground.